# Colored Emojis in Java Swing Labels

Tags: java, swing, unicode, fonts, emoji

I was wondering how to dispaly colored emojis in swing. I have a feeling that the Swing (awt) font engine is unable to do this. I've tried using the windows emoji font (`Segoe UI Emoji`), but sadly it only displays the monochrome variants. Is there any UIManager-Property or Client-Property that I can set in order to get the non-monochrome variant or is Swing simply unable to do this?

I have also noticed that by default Swing doesn't display emoji at all. I thought that if there is an emoji font available, that there'd be some kind of fallback. Usually an emoji font doesn't contain things besides emoji as far as I understand. So for example I would use `Segoe UI` which would use `Segoe UI Emoji` for the emojis. On the other hand it should be possible to use `Segoe UI` for the normal text and `Noto Color Emoji` for the emojis. Am I missunderstanding something here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Swing is not built to support colored emojis.

Those are usually rendered by web browsers, so the Java-FX `WebView` might be able to support them (AFAIU it actually embeds a browser).

Swing, OTOH was designed to handle a *sub-set* of HTML ***3.2*** (yes, it's *that* old).

Answer (score 0):

As of java 17, color emojis are now supported by swing (at least on macOS). Jira ticket [here](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8263583), and github pr [here](https://github.com/openjdk/jdk/pull/3007).